# Showing number of images user inputs? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to be alerted and have to input a number. The corresponding number of images will appear. I have this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE hmtl>
 <html>
    <head>
   <script>
//creating my function
    function howMany(){
        var numBurgers = parseInt(prompt('How many burgers do you want?', "3"));
        var x = "";

        for(var count = 0; count < numBurgers; count++;){
            x += "<img src=\"burger.jpg\" />";
        }

        document.getElementById('burgerImages').innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="howMany();">
   <div id="burgerImages"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Someone suggested that I replace "document.getElementById('burgerImages').innerHTML = x;"
with "document.getElementById('burgerImages').appendChild(x)."
but that does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: For `appendChild` the argument passed should be an actual DOM element created by `document.createElement` and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because `appendChild` expect the parameter to be a [`Node Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) not a string.

You need to create different nodes, and then append those nodes :

```
var fragmentCollection = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < numBurgers; i++) {       
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('src', 'burger.jpg');
    fragmentCollection.appendChild(img);
}
var burgerContainer = document.getElementById('burgerImages');
burgerContainer.appendChild(fragmentCollection);
```

References:

- [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)
- [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)